# "I saw him [while] 'cross'/'crossing' the road"

Tags: infinitives, gerunds

1. I saw him *cross* the road.
2. I saw him *crossing* the road.
3. I saw him *while cross* the road.
4. I saw him *while crossing* the road.

What is the difference in meaning between 1 and 2? Can we add *while* before *cross* and *crossing* like in 3 and 4? If so, what does *while* add to the meaning of 1 and 2? If nothing, can we infer that 1 and 2 are elliptical forms of 3 and 4?

Answer (score 2):

The difference between sentences 1 and 2 is very subtle. If you say ***see someone do*** something, then you saw the entire action, form beginning to end. If you ***see them doing*** something, then you caught them in the middle of it.

For example, "I saw the baby crawl from the sofa to the table". - you saw the whole thing. On the other hand, "I saw the baby crawling in the bedroom." - you saw the baby at some point while it was crawling, maybe you entered the bedroom and it was right there, on the floor, crawling.

On the other hand, sentences like "I saw the baby smile" and "I saw the baby smiling" would not be so clearly defined.

As a **general rule** (do not forget, this is English and it does not always apply), if you use the infinitive, you see the complete action; if you use the -ing form, you see part of it, you see it in progress.

Sentence 3 is incorrect in my opinion. As for sentence 4, after while it is a good idea to say who because the way it is written now it could mean either "I saw him while I was crossing the road", or "I saw him while he was crossing the road".

Comment: I agree everything except maybe the last sentence. In practice, I think the default "subject" of ***while** crossing the road* in OP's example #4 would always be **I**. If that wasn't what you meant, you wouldn't use the word "while" in the first place.